# OSError: broken data stream when reading image file

Tags: python-3.5, keras

I am trying to read an image file using Image package of Keras.

Here is my code.

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
img_path = 'test/test_image.jpg'  # This is an image I took in my kitchen.
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
```

When I run the code, I get the following error.

```
anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py in load(self)
    238         if not self.map and not LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES and err_code < 0:
    239             # still raised if decoder fails to return anything
--> 240             raise_ioerror(err_code)
    241 
    242         # post processing

anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py in raise_ioerror(error)
     57     if not message:
     58         message = "decoder error %d" % error
---> 59     raise IOError(message + " when reading image file")
     60 
     61 

OSError: broken data stream when reading image file
```

Please note, if I convert `test_image.jpg` to `test_image.png`, then the given code works perfectly. But I have several thousands of pictures and I can't convert all of them to png format. I tried several things after searching for solution in web but couldn't get rid of the problem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use this at the beginning of your code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
```

I found it [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1510). And this is working for me.

Comment: Note that images loaded using this flag set to True might not be well interpreted as indicated in the linked github issue. In my case, this indeed avoided OSError.

Answer (score 4):

According to [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1057#issuecomment-219211437) `Pillow` upgrade by `pip install Pillow --upgrade` should solve this issue.

If you are still facing the problem you can use `mogrify` to batch convert all your images. `mogrify -format png *.jpg`

Comment: when I try to update pillow, it says, pillow is already to its latest version. I didn't try the `mogrify` command though.