# How to install package ffmpeg in google colab

Tags: ffmpeg, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to use Google Colab to do something. Particularly I want to use *ffmpeg* package to [create a video from a image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44951066/6890234).

But ffmpeg doesn't seems to be working fine.

The output of this (in the last block) was supposed to be **`400 400`** instead of **`0 0`**

```
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))
print frame_width, frame_height
```

The same code is working fine with Azure notebooks and also on my local machine.

What can be the reason for it? And how to rectify that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to install `ffmpeg` first:

```
!apt install ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://pytorch.org/audio/main/tutorials/streamreader_advanced_tutorial.html#streamreader-advanced-usages:%7E:text=To%20enable%20running%20this%20notebook%20in%20Google%20Colab%2C%20install%20the%20requisite%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20third%20party%20libraries%20by%20running%20the%20following%20code%3A), the following commands worked for me:

```
! add-apt-repository -y ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4
! apt-get -qq install -y ffmpeg
```