# Write 2 images into a video using OpenCV (Python) of 10 seconds duration

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to take 2 images present in a local folder and use OpenCV's Videowriter function to create a video from these images. 
I am using FrameRate of 1. So this creates a video of 2 seconds duration. Below is the code (I got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44947505/how-to-make-a-movie-out-of-images-in-python)):

```
import cv2
import os

image_folder = 'images'
video_name = 'video.avi'

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".png")]
frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, 0, 1, (width,height))

for image in images:
    video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Goal: I want to create a video of 10 seconds which will have these 2 images each being displayed for 5 seconds.

I think there might be a similar question like this in the forum but I am not able to find it. If someone can point me to the solution, it would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: whats the bug you have? and where you are stuck at?  if you are using timing to control the output. Then shouldn`t you have a while loop, while not over 10 sec time. In if in first 5 sec do thing, else in later 5 sec do another, cv:;waitkey or direct timing/sequence check.  not very sure fps can be 1 or not. usually it 15 -30. and we just pad the same image eover and over again.

Comment: Why not just use `ffmpeg`? If your stills are called `image1.png` and `image2.png`, you can just run `ffmpeg -r 0.2 -i image%d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p video.avi`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below code snippet should solve your problem. Notice that you will have to specify `each_image_duration`. I used this variable to write the each image in the video for a specific duration. For this use case, you have to keep the `fps` as `1.0`, so each video frame will be displayed for `1.0 sec`. This makes the 3rd argument in `cv2.Videowriter`.

```
import cv2
import os

image_folder = 'images'
video_name = 'video.avi'
each_image_duration = 5 # in secs
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') # define the video codec

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".png")]
frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, fourcc, 1.0, (width, height))

for image in images:
    for _ in range(each_image_duration):
        video.write(cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, image)))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```

Comment: Thank you @Dr Yuan Shenghai for the idea. I didn't think of padding the same image again and again for 5 secs which now seems the obvious thing to do. 
And thank you Aditya for implementing this idea.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with 400 images but what happens is that from time to time a lot of images are displayed for less than 1 sec and then one image stays on the screen for 10 secs (I used image duration as 2).

Answer (score 0):

Here you can calculate fps dynamically based on how many frames you have and how many seconds of video you want to make.

See code below:

```
import cv2
import os

image_folder = 'images'
video_name = 'video.avi'

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID') # define the video codec

images = [img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".png")]
img_count = len(images)
video_secs = 10
frame = cv2.imread(os.path.join(image_folder, images[0]))
height, width, layers = frame.shape

video = cv2.VideoWriter(video_name, fourcc, float(img_count/video_secs), (width, height))

for image in images:
    video.write(image)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
video.release()
```