# Making a video with images in Python using opencv on Mac

Tags: video, opencv, python

I have some graphs within a folder called jupyter with jpg format, I want to put them together to make a video out of them, but when I run the code, it does not save and show the video.

```
import cv2
import os
from os.path import isfile, join
def convert_pictures_to_video(pathIn, pathOut, fps, time):
    frame_array=[]
    files= [f for f in os.listdir(pathIn) if isfile(join(pathIn,f))]
    for i in range (len(files)):
        filename=pathIn+files[i]
        img=cv2.imread(filename)
        height, width, layers=img.shape
        size=(width,height)
        for k in range (time):
        frame_array.append(img)
out=cv2.VideoWriter(pathOut, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),fps,size)

    for i in range(len(frame_array)):
        out.write(frame_array[i])
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    out.release()

pathIn='/Users/jupyter/'
pathOut='/Users/jupyter/video.avi'
fps=1
time=20
convert_pictures_to_video(pathIn, pathOut, fps, time
```

Comment: You have a typo there, read again. You need `release`.

Comment: Do not use OpenCV to create videos.  The backend to create the videos is horribly bloated - you have no control on the quality factor which tends to create really large file sizes.  I recommend `moviepy` instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62434934/3250829

Comment: Thanks, I edited the typo but still does not work.

Comment: @rayryeng Why not directly use something like ffmpeg rather than yet another wrapper though?

Comment: @matanster You could. I've done this in the past where I've set up a pipe that directly uses FFMPEG but I suggested moviepy for those who don't really know how to use FFMPEG.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 1. You want to create a `.avi` file from your images. Therefore you should initialize `fourcc` to `MJPG`.

  - ```py
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')
    ```
  - You should use `mp4v` when you want to create a `.mp4` file

    - ```py
      fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
      ```
- 2. All Images's size and the `VideoWriter` size must be same.

     For instance: All my images are with the size (300, 167). Therefore:

     - ```py
       out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', fourcc, 25, (300, 167), isColor=True)
       ```
     - Since, I'm going to create colorful images, I set the `isColor` variable to true
- 3. I prefer `glob` for gathering all images:

     - ```py
       for img in sorted(glob.glob("ball_tracking/*.png")):
           img = cv2.imread(img)
           img = cv2.resize(img, (300, 167))
           out.write(img)
       ```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import glob

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G')

out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', fourcc, 25, (300, 167), isColor=True)

for img in sorted(glob.glob("ball_tracking/*.png")):
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (300, 167))
    out.write(img)

out.release()
```

Update

---

- If the quality is really bad, you could do two-things. For slowing the video you can lower the frame-rate.

  - 1. Changing `.avi` to `.mp4`

    - ```py
      fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
      ```
  - 2. You can change the `image size`. For instance, if all of you images are the same size. Then get the first images' height and width and set it to the video's size.

    - ```py
       (h, w) = cv2.imread(glob("<your-path-here>*.png")[0]).shape[:2]
      ```
    - If your images are not same you can still use the above code, but the quality may not be improved.
  - 3. You could lower the frame-rate for slower video. For instance: 25 to 2.

    - ```py
      out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.avi', fourcc, 2, (w, h), isColor=True)
      ```

Updated Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import glob

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'P', '4', 'V')
(h, w) = cv2.imread(glob("<your-path-here>*.png")[0]).shape[:2]

out = cv2.VideoWriter('video.mp4', fourcc, 2, (w, h), isColor=True)

for img in sorted(glob.glob("<your-path-here>*.png")):
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (w, h))
    out.write(img)

out.release()
```

Comment: I can run it without any error, but it does not show any results and the output is not saved, time of the run in less than a second which does not make sense. In addition, my files should be uploaded in order, like, image1.png, image2.png,...

Comment: You made the necessary changes right? I mean you changed `ball_tracking/*.png` to your current directory, and you are sure about all the files extensions are `.png`? I've tested the code before placing here.

Comment: Absolutely, yes, I changed it, I realized it was saved in another directory, so it works, I have 2 concerns: the quality is very bad, 2- The video is very quick, can I make it slower?

Comment: I've updated my code. If you want you could look at it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved the resolution problem by changing the numbers in "cv2.resize(img, (1200, 668))", when I run the update code I get this error:"TypeError: 'module' object is not callable". In addition, I need to read the images in order, like image1.png, image2.png, ...

Comment: Yes I did change it

Comment: It was solved, I just need to know how I can read the images in order.